# YouTube embed video not displaying using <a href>

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I am trying to implement you tube embed video using  `<a href>`. it seems not displaying the youtube video and unresponsive. I am not seeing any issue in Jquery or CSS issue. It's working with `<iframe src>` but not working with `<a href>` and would like to implement with `a tag`

No working:

```
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" target="_blank" class="youtube-play-icon launch-youtube-modal"></a>
```

Working:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" target="_blank" class="youtube-play-icon launch-youtube-modal"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why do you want this with an `a` tag? Why not just use iframe?

Comment: @Barskey I would like to redirect it to another page.

Comment: As Will stated earlier, the point of an `iframe` is to show the content on the page itself, if you want the user to watch the video on youtube you should probably just use the anchor tag with text.

Also, if you hover over the video in the `iframe` and then click the video title you will be redirected to youtube.

Answer (score 1):

A link doesn't seem to have a point unless you want the person to visit another page to view the video. The iframe will display the video without the person leaving the page

Comment: I would like to redirect it to another page.

Comment: @Nisarg there is no text in the <a>  input here  </a> tag. Was it not visible to click on? If so, just add the text you want to click on

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Added a input text but nothing changed.